# Adobe LiveCycle working with Repeating Subforms

Tags: javascript, repeat, livecycle, subforms

I have repeating subforms with buttons on them. 
I want to be able to remove buttons that have been added with each addition of a subform.
By the searching I've done, the following code should work, but it doesn't. Can someone please set me straight?

```
var IGdelbut = xfa.resolveNodes("ItemGroup[*].ItemHeader.Delbutton");
for (var i = 0; i < IGdelbut; i++) {
    IGdelbut.presence = "invisible";
}
```

(I apologize for repeating my earlier question, but I'm hoping I'm giving someone better information to work with.)

Comment: What XFA event do your put the script into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script has a couple of issues iterating over the result of `resolveNodes()` call. If i get this right, you are trying to hide all the **DelButton**s on the subforms.

Try the following

```
var allDeleteButtons = xfa.resolveNodes("ItemGroup[*].ItemHeader.Delbutton");
var len = allDeleteButtons.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    allDeleteButtons.item(i).presence = "invisible";
}
```

Assuming you have this script on the parent subform of repeating **ItemGroup** subforms.

Comment: Just what the doctor ordered! Thank you very much. Your second line never seemed to show up in any of the examples I tried to emulate. (In answer to your earlier question, this is in a mouseUp event).